# Sorting the return of a MySQL PHP PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-order-by

I am creating a website for my network and I have a basic CMS on the home page that shows news articles. It all works apart from one thing, the newest post is at the bottom of the list and the oldest is at the top. I would like the newest at the top and the oldest at the bottom. I am using PDO for fetching the news and PHP to display it. Here is the fetch news code:

```
<?php
class Article{

    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($id) {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE  article_id = ? ");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetch();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `order by` clause with `desc` – descending order:

```
order by article_id desc
```

Comment: Where the hell IS ulysses then?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC");
```

Edit: Accidentally copied the wrong query, concept remains the same.

Comment: You've chosen the wrong query – in this one there would be only one record – nothing to sort.

Comment: And here comes another one: how does that differ  from my answer?)

Comment: Are you saying that folks cannot post duplicate answers on a post @notulysses? I see it all of the time.

Comment: Both will work fine. Yours will sort the articles in descending order of the ID, therefore as they were entered into the DB and given their ID number. However, in my answer, sorting by a date field would still sort articles "correctly" even if OP were to post a "backdated" article.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard : Well, the interval between posts is a matter of discussion.Actually, I didn't notice the `article_date`/`article_id`, sorry. Maybe it is just because it haven't exist in the first place, but I get the logic.)

Comment: @notulysses What's the discussion to be had re: interval between posts?

Comment: True @notulysses, very true. But it is still possible to be distracted by something else and not see the other answer for several minutes because the other person may have started to answer, got distracted and then came back to finish up. It's happened to me before.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify fetch_all() and you should be good.

```
public function fetch_all() {
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_id DESC");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```